# How to set FORM inputs and action in AMP Html email template

Tags: html, forms, email, html-email, amp-html

I am sending emails with an amp-template which has a form. When I got this email template thunderbird display nothing, yandex mail app display two brachets and outlook display form very well but I couldn't post anything to my website.

If you have any solutions, I will be very happy

```
<form  class="proceed__form" method="GET" id="requirements-form"
              action-xhr="https://stevepaper.com/"
              target="_top">
              <div class="m1">
                <input type="text" class="inputla" name="name" placeholder="Your name .. " id="name">
                <input type="email" class="inputla" name="email" placeholder="Your email .. " id="email">
                <input type="text" class="inputla" name="subject" placeholder="Subject (Math or History ..)" id="subject">
                
                <textarea autoexpand  type="text-area" class="inputla" name="message" placeholder="Your message .. " id="message"></textarea>
              </div>

              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Gönder" name="gonder">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <div class="m1" submit-success>
                <template type="amp-mustache">
                  Subscription successful!
                </template>
              </div>
              <div class="m1" submit-error>
                <template type="amp-mustache">
                  Subscription failed!
                </template>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

AMP is only supported by Gmail, Mail.ru and Outlook.com at the moment.
So unfortunal you cant use AMP-for-email if your audience use another email clients.
You can read more about it [here](https://amp.dev/about/email/)

Comment: I think you're technically correct, but it may be clearer to say: you'll need normal HTML for most email clients, and if you are supplying the text-x-amphtml MIME type, that will only get used by those clients that support it, namely Gmail, Mail.ru and Outlook.com at the moment.

Comment: @Nathan True, I'm just not sure of the behavior for none-supported email clients. Maybe they will show some content in a strange way or nothing at all. It needs to be tested if this is the solution they are going for :)

Answer (score 0):

Yandex doesn't support both @media and AMP

And I suppose it's forever =/

But you can use AMP in combine with a simple HTML that will be shown if AMP is not supported.